# transfer the same relation to the core

Tags: laravel, oop, relation

i have CoreModel extends from Model

```
class CoreModel extends Model
{
```

and I extended all the models from coreModel

```
class Product extends CoreModel
```

most tables have an author_id column that belongsTo with User

```
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('author_id')->constrained('users')
```

inside each model I have to create

```
public function author(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'author_id');
}
```

I need something like that. this relationship ni
I need to move to coreModel but it should work with condition  if this model has **author_id** in `protected $fillable`

### What do you advise to do ?

> I was thinking about writing **trait** .but I still have to do it on every model **use** this trait

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### I also used Trait as said [@Bulent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4925548/bulent)

```
trait Author
{
    /**
     * adding author_id
     * @return void
     */
    protected static function bootAuth(): void
    {
        static::creating(function ($query) {
            $query->author_id = $query->author_id ?? auth()->id();
        });
    }

    public function author()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'author_id');
    }
}
```

.

```
class Category extends Model
{
    use Author;
```

Answer (score 2):

In such cases, using traits provides an easier way.

```
trait BelongsToUser
{
    public function author(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'author_id');
    }
}
```

```
class Product extends Model
{
    use BelongsToUser;
}
```

Comment: Your answer is correct. I also thought about it, but I was afraid that other project participants would forget about it.That's why I thought to put it on core